# How to run a php script locally with webpage

Tags: php, html

I am not sure is this is a correct place to ask for help or but. Say I have php script which calculates prime numbers and store in database. Now I want to create a webpage and a button on that page that instructs prime_numbers.php file to run. How can I achieve this?

```
<? php
    // Database connection
    // call a function to find a prime number
    // store prime numbers in database. I don't care about duplicate numbers or data duplication
?>
```

Since the code for this file is too trival and doesn't matter what it does, I am not posting actual code.

Answer (score 0):

This is too basic a question.

You need to code the page in the HTML that passes request to PHP then PHP should display the output HTML however like I said its the start of the PHP learning so best check the links below

CodeAcademy : https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php or http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: May be too basic. But I couldn't find solution online. This is why I asked question here

Comment: No i mean this is the absolute start to php learning so go through the tutorials a bit as starter that shows how to install a webserver like Apache and code your Hello world .:).

Answer (score 0):

You can use event on the button and in this event call this script via ajax.

```
$('#btn').click( function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: prime_numbers.php,
      )};
}

<input type="button" id="btn"></input>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any other way without ajax. Thanks for help. Much appreciated.

Comment: is that way that you call location.href which redirect you to a script. I don't know what you want from this script or just run ? Don't need any variables or values send there or anything get back ?

Comment: No need to send values, no need to get result. Just a site with button that's it. I press button and script starts running.

Comment: According me ajax is the best choice for you. I don't know better way to do this so.

Comment: okay thank you. One more thing is there any way to press a button within webpage after a certain time interval infinitely.

Comment: The way exists but i do not know how to do it.